# What's wrong with this integral calculation?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to calculate the integral
$$I = \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^2 \theta\ \cos^4 \theta\  d \theta$$
by converting it into a complex integral around the unit circle.

I use the identities
$$\cos \theta = {1 \over 2} (e^{i \theta} + e^{-i \theta}),$$
$$\sin \theta = {1 \over 2 i} (e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta})$$
and let
$$z = e^{i \theta}$$
to convert the integral to
$$I = \oint_C ({1 \over 2 i} (z - {1 \over z}))^2 ({1 \over 2} (z + {1 \over z}))^4\ dz$$
$$=-{1 \over 64} \oint_C (z - {1 \over z})^2 (z + {1 \over z})^4\ dz$$
Then, to apply Cauchy's residue theorem, I note that the integrand has a single pole, which is at the origin ($z = 0$). The polynomial expansion of the integrand is
$$z^6+2 z^4-z^2-4-{1\over z^2}+{2\over z^4}+{1\over z^6}$$
so this pole has a residue of $0$, as the expansion has no $z^{-1}$ term.

By the residue theorem, therefore,
$$\oint_C (z - {1 \over z})^2 (z + {1 \over z})^4\ dz = 2 \pi i\ 
\text{Res}_{z=0} [(z - {1 \over z})^2 (z + {1 \over z})^4] = 0$$
which means that 
$$I = 0.$$

But this is obviously wrong. The real integral at the top is strictly non-negative, and is not always $0$, so its integral must be positive. (In fact, the integral is $\pi \over 8$.)

Where have I gone wrong in the complex analysis?

Comment: Aren't you missing a factor $z^{-1}$ in the original line integral?

Comment: I don't think so. Where do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought $dz=i e^{i\theta}d\theta$ or $d\theta=\frac{dz}{i z}.$

EDIT: Added $i$ to the denominator.

Comment: Huh. You're probably right. Let me see if that fixes it.

Comment: Then I end up with the contour integral being $-8 \pi i$, which leaves me with $I = {i \pi \over 8}$ instead of $\pi \over 8$. How do I get rid of that extra $i$?

Comment: I mean, the pole then has a residue of $-4$, which gives me $I = -{1 \over 64}\times 2 \pi i\  \text{Res}_{z=0}f(z) = {i \pi \over 8}$.

Comment: $dz=i\exp(i\theta)d\theta$

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks! I'm still trying to wrap my head around basic complex analysis, and your help is ... really helpful!